# Why the ISO C++ standard forbids the initialization for members?

Tags: c++, initialization, standards

Why i can't do that

```
class A {
  public:

    int x = 10;

  ...
};
```

and I have to do that ?

```
class A {
  public:

    int x;

  A(){
    x = 10;
    ...
  }

  ...
};
```

It's because C++ is trying to be more type safe than languages like C ? There are other reasons ?

Comment: Perfectly valid in C++11. In C++03, you use initalizer lists.

Comment: In C++11, you can initialize at the point of declaration.

Comment: It's better to use initialization lists than to do what you did in your second example.

Comment: @chris C++11 is still not really supported on a broad range of platform, i need something much more portable. I also like to know more how C++ was designed to be.

Comment: @axis, I'm not sure why they didn't include it in C++03, but that doesn't mea.n you can't initialize your data members. Some do get initialized automatically as well.

Comment: FWIW, C++03 allows initialization for `static const` members.  It seems to me that C++03 doesn't allow non-`static`, non-`const` members to be initialized that way but C++11 does means that they just didn't think of it or didn't get agreement about it, not that there are any safety concerns.

Comment: It probably just wasn't thought of, or if it was it was too untested so it never made it through. Sometimes there's no fundamental reason, it's just how things ended up.

Comment: @jamesdlin, Is that not only for integral types as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with type safety, both examples are as safe.

When creating a language you need to define what is allowed and what is not. Since writing a blacklist would be a never-ending experience, a language is usually written in a white-list fashion, adding more and more possible things.

However, one should not allow things without clearly weighing the consequences. Whenever you want to allow something new, you need to check:

- the ease of implementation
- the interaction with other existing features and known probable extensions

Furthermore, it also means that there is more to learn for those wishing to use the language.

What you are asking for here is, however, relatively easy. It can be seen as the counterpart, for classes, to functions default arguments. This has been adopted in C++11 because it was the simplest way to guarantee a coherence of the default values when writing multiple constructors.

Personally, when using C++11, I recommend initializing all built-in types this way (if only to `0`), much like I recommend initializing them when declaring local variables: this way you cannot forget to initialize them in one of the constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Warning: Speculation follows.

C++ classes were based on C structs, with a number of added features. Members of C structures can't have initializers (because it would require code to be executed every time an object of the structure type is created, something that was considered too complex for early C compilers).

Early C++ (originally called "C with Classes") added constructors, a mechanism that does require code to be executed every time an object of a given type is created. Since a constructor can do everything that a member initializer could do, member initializers were probably seen as unnecessary.

But as you imply in your question, it would be *convenient* to have member initializers, even if it isn't strictly necessary. And the new 2011 ISO C++ standard has added that feature to the language, so apparently the ISO C++ committee agreed that they're a good idea. This feature increases the complexity of the language (for example, there have to be new rules governing the order in which initializers and constructors are executed, and code that depends on that order will be potentially confusing). The committee decided that the convenience was worth the added complexity. (I *think* I agree.)

(Bjarne Stroustrup, the inventor of the C++ language, has a book, "[The Design and Evolution of C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543303)", that discusses his early design decisions. I haven't (yet) checked it to see whether he mentions this particular issue.)

Summary: Member initializers are *convenient* but not *necessary*, and it simply took a while to decide to add them as a language feature.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, pure simplicity of the language.

There is certain value in having the language compact. Disallowing your first example, the language is not posing any serious limitations, right? As a result you have thinner book, simpler compiler. These advantages are debatable. Please, do not consider them as something  appriory correct. I personally see value in compactness. Exceptional success of C can be partly attributed to its simplicity and compactness.

With introduction of C++11 the situation is moving in the direction that less and less people will know the language `significantly deep`. This **WILL** have negative consequences. I am not stating that only negative though.

Comment: "*With introduction of C++11 the situation is moving in the direction that less and less people will know the language entirely.*" I would say that few people know C++03 "entirely". Many people *think* they know C++03 "entirely", but they don't. Most of the people who really do will learn C++11 just as "entirely" as they did C++03 because they *have* to know it "entirely" to do what they do. Remember: most people only know a language well enough to get done what they need to get done.

Comment: I mean here `entirely` maybe as `well enough to use is it effectively`. Level of good knowledge of C++11 will drop in comparison with C++03.

Comment: Who decides what "use is [sic] it effectively" or "significantly deep" means? Some might say that if you don't know how to use SFINAE in C++03, you're not using the language "effectively." That if you don't know how to use the traits idiom, then your knowledge isn't "significantly deep" in C++03. It's a completely subjective measurement based on what *you* value in your C++ code.

Comment: I am afraid you are more discussing used words than the idea behind them...

Comment: All I have to go on *are* your words. If your words do not adequately communicate your intended meaning, then please change them so that they do. If you have some non-subjective criteria for determining what constitutes sufficient C++ knowledge, then bring it forth. Otherwise, you're making a subjective assessment of people's knowledge based on your own arbitrary metric. A lot of people get along in C++ just fine using "C with Classes" style programming; for them, that is "significantly deep" enough. C++11 will bring them useful tools, but they won't suddenly start adopting modern C++ idioms.

Comment: Wow, that is taking "comm" out of "communication" which is a reciprocal process. It is easy to accuse anyone of not speaking with mathematical precision, but the accuser would be committing the same crime as soon as he opens his mouth.